# PHP exec find doesnt work

Tags: php

I'm trying to recursively chmod all directories with php, and using:

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Works great from the command line, but using it from the server:

```
exec('find /path/to/dir -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;');
```

Does nothing. Any ideas? Is it permission related? The path is the real path server level.

Comment: You've already set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, right?

Comment: Of course, thats the first thing I did to check for errors

Comment: The `exec` version is missing the `3` from the first one.

Comment: Use `passthru()` to view the output

Comment: That was a spelling mistake, edited

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe use the full path to the `find` binary?  It might not be in the path.

Comment: passthru() shows nothing, and using full path to find does nothing... strange problem

Comment: What OS are you running?  Maybe something RHEL-based like CentOS?

Comment: Linux 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64 Cent OS

Comment: Run `sudo tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log` in a terminal while hitting the page in your browser.  I bet you'll see SELinux errors.  If you don't have root... well, I still bet it's SELinux.

Comment: Curses!  Does the `/selinux` directory exist, and if so, does it have a file called `enforcing`?  If so, does `enforcing` contain 0 or 1?  If the directory does not exist, or enforcing is turned off, then it's *not* SELinux.

Comment: there is a folder: etc/selinux. no enforcing

Comment: Unfortunately that was my best guess.

Comment: What happens when you try the command from the CLI, after a `su apache` (or is it `www-data`?)

Answer (score 2):

When you run it on the command line, you're running it as your user which probably is the owner of the path. When you exec() from PHP it is the Apache user that is doing it. Only the owner a a file/dir can chmod it. To confirm this is the case, try to run your exec() script from the [PHP CLI Interactive Shell](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php). Within the Interactive Shell, you can run PHP code but it will execute as your user.

If that turns out to be the cause, you must first chown the dir and it's sub files/dirs to be owned by the Apache user.